# WAS MQ put by JmsConnectionFactory host unreachable

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm using this part of code for connect to a queue manager.

```
jmsFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
jcf = jmsFactory.createConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName);
jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);

connection = jcf.createConnection();
```

When everything is OK, there is no problem. But when host is unreachable; there is a long wait for get an exception. I mean `jcf.createConnection()` waiting and trying to get connection around 30 seconds and then raise an exception.

Can I decrease this time? and how?
when in another application I tried to send thousand of messages by thread to a queue manager and each thread waiting for 30 second to get connection, it caused serious problems.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked the timeout isn't at an operating system level?  Also, is the queue manager local (on the same machine as your code runs) or remote?

Comment: No I run my app in another system. I want handle a situation which my QMGR server is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that your [reconnectionRetryInterval](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031660_.htm) is set at the default value, which I believe is 30 seconds.

Comment: You're right, but this interval can be used when QMGR is up. My problem is when IP can not ping; when IP is down. I think I have to set some parameters in JmsFactoryFactory properties to change timeout from 30 seconds to 10 seconds; but I don't know how.